# smd_private.h: No such file or directory

Tags: android, c

I'm trying to build a stand alone Android kernel and i want to write loadable kernel module, but when i build my module.c file, i  have this error

```
error: smd_private.h: No such file or directory
```

search at google told me that i should change `<smd_private.h>` into `"smd_private.h"` .but the error still exist!!
Can you help me?

Comment: You really need to include specifics of how you are building - especially if your intent is to use `arch/arm/mach-msm/smd_private.h` proper specification of the target will be essential.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure smd_private.h is in the same directory as my module.c

Here is info from https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Include-Syntax.html#Include-Syntax

```
2.1 Include Syntax
    Both user and system header files are included using the preprocessing 
    directive ‘#include’. It has two variants:

    #include <file>
    This variant is used for system header files. It searches for a file 
    named file in a standard list of system directories. You can prepend 
    directories to this list with the -I option (see Invocation). 

    #include "file"
    This variant is used for header files of your own program. It searches 
    for a file named file first in the directory containing the current 
    file, then in the quote directories and then the same directories used
    for <file>. You can prepend directories to the list of quote directories 
    with the -iquote option.

    The argument of ‘#include’, whether delimited with quote marks or angle 
    brackets, behaves like a string constant in that comments are not 
    recognized, and macro names are not expanded. Thus, #include <x/*y> 
    specifies inclusion of a system header file named x/*y.

    However, if backslashes occur within file, they are considered ordinary 
    text characters, not escape characters. None of the character escape 
    sequences appropriate to string constants in C are processed. 
    Thus, #include "x\n\\y" specifies a filename containing three 
    backslashes. (Some systems interpret ‘\’ as a pathname separator. 
    All of these also interpret ‘/’ the same way. It is most portable to 
    use only ‘/’.)

    It is an error if there is anything (other than comments) on the line 
    after the file name.
```

Comment: The reference may well be to arch/arm/mach-msm/smd_private.h rather than something for the specific driver being built.  If so, it suggests an issue with improper selection of a build configuration omitting this include directory.